# CIFilter.outputImage is nil?

Tags: swift, null, cifilter, ciimage

when I run the following in two MAC PCs, one is OK, the other is NG, so I don't know how to resolve the problem, if you know the reason, please give me some ideas.

Note: I found some similar questions, but they almost relate to the timing of processes when it was converted from CIImage into UIImage. so I think this question maybe is different with them.

IOS version: 11

```
    let barCode : String = "BPWE-12-WBTDJ-23WES-9F7D9"
    let data = barCode.data(using: .utf8)
    guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") else {
        return
    }
    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    guard let ciImage = filter.outputImage else {   //here is nil
        return
    }
```

Comment: are you sure data isn't nil, sometimes? Perhaps the string isn't valid utf8?

Comment: Could not replicate your issue. Your `ciImage` is not `nil`. I guess your issue is when you try to get a PNG or JPEG data representation from it is returning `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

I have gotten the answer.
first of all, I need to say sorry for everyone, since I made a mistake, there was a little difference with variable barCode between two of my MAC PCs, one is assigned by using UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString.
as you know that when it was run at simulator, it maybe doesn't works well, of course, it can works well on real iPad or iPhone.

so when I change value of variable barCode instead of using UUID,  I resolved the problem.

thank for all of you.